# WP rest api v2 posts filter by 'search' & 'category_name' not working

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I am calling the api as `http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=uncategorize&per_page=30&order=asc&search=hello`

I am not able to get particular posts from that specific category. I got all results from all categories.Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter parameter was removed as part of WP 4.7, to get the results you expect you'll need to change

```
http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=uncategorize&per_page=30&order=asc&search=hello
```

to

```
http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1&per_page=30&order=asc&search=hello
```

Make sure to change `categories=0` to whatever `uncategorised`'s `tag_ID` is.

If you'd like to restore the Filter parameter, I would recommend this plugin: https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter

Comment: Thankssssss Thankssssss Thankssssss Thankssssss Thankssssss

Comment: http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1&per_page=30&order=asc&search=hello